# Query to select 1000 records with Multi Primary Key so that I can verify the data is mapping between two DB

Tags: sql-server, oracle

**Background:** data migration from Oracle to SQL Server, Table A exists both in Oracle and SQL Server.

Table A has 4 columns as primary key in Oracle, and it has been copied to SQL Server. When I selected 1000 records from Table A in Oracle, how to select the same records in SQL Server using one query?

SQL in Oracle:

```
SELECT 
    A, B, C, D
FROM 
    (SELECT ROWNUM AS RN, T1.* FROM T1)
WHERE 
    RN > 0 AND RN <= 1000
```

Comment: if you are looking for selecting data together from MSSQL and Oracle, you can think about creating LIKNED Server in MSSQL.

Comment: @mkRabbani, thanks, but I only have select permission to access those two DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you need the same 1000 records when the same query is executed on both the servers individually.

You can achieve this using either of the following queries:

1) Using `ROWNUM` with the `order by`

```
SELECT A, B, C, D FROM
(SELECT A, B, C, D, ROWNUM AS RN
  FROM (SELECT T1.* FROM T1 ORDER BY A, B, C, D))
 WHERE RN > 0
   AND RN <= 1000
```

2) Using `ROW_NUMBER` windows function

```
SELECT A, B, C, D
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A, B, C, D) AS RN, T1.* FROM T1)
 WHERE RN > 0
   AND RN <= 1000
```

Cheers!!